# Broadcast receiver not working for INITIALIZE_PROGRAMS action

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, adb, android-tv

I'm developing an Android TV app, and I'm setting up a broadcast receiver to run a work class when the user installs the app.
Following the Google [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations-channel#creating_a_channel), topic number 6, it shows how to add a receiver in the manifest file with the action "android.media.tv.action.INITIALIZE_PROGRAMS".
I did that, and also created a simple broadcast receiver class as showed bellow:

```
class TvLauncherReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    Log.d("print", "onReceive ${intent.action}")
}
```

As described in the documentation, I have to run the following adb command to trigger the broadcast action, as the app was not installed from the play store:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.media.tv.action.INITIALIZE_PROGRAMS -n \
your.package.name/.YourReceiverName
```

I have done all that, the terminal shows me that the Broadcast was completed, but nothing happens. Added a breakpoint and onReceive is not even been called.

Am I missing something there?

Thank you!

Comment: If your manifest matches what they show in step 6, try removing `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`. That's not usually used with `<receiver>` elements. It's also possible that the documentation is out of date, as [implicit broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) like those no longer work in general.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @CommonsWare. I tried removing the DEFAULT category but it still didn't work. It's weird because I downloaded their codelabs in (https://developer.android.com/codelabs/tv-recommendations-kotlin#0) which has this broadcast implemented. Tested and it worked fine, so there might be something else that is blocking it on my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that everything was setup fine. The problem is: The project that I'm working on has a applicationId suffix set in the build.gradle file. Therefore, the correct adb command should be:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.media.tv.action.INITIALIZE_PROGRAMS -n \
your.package.name.applicationIdSuffix/.YourReceiverName
```

If you find yourself with this same issue, make sure to check your build.gradle file for an applicationIdSuffix variable.